# How do i take sum by selecting checkbox and values in span and show total in another span

Tags: jquery, checkbox, event-handling

I need to select checkbox and grab the values from span and show the sum in another span having id of amount

```
 <div class="col1">
          <div class="field">
            <div class="label-wrap">
              <label class="required" for="buy_form_pwd2">Books Required</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrap">
              <input type="checkbox" id="you-are" name="total">Book Name<span style="margin-left:10px;">Price</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">No of Books<input style="width: 45px;" type="number" placeholder="1"></span><span style="margin-left:10px;">250</span><br><hr style="margin:0;">
              <input type="checkbox" id="you-are" name="total">Book Name<span style="margin-left:10px;">Price</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">No of Books<input style="width: 45px;" type="number" placeholder="1"></span><span style="margin-left:10px;">375</span><br><hr style="margin:0;">
              <input type="checkbox" id="you-are" name="total">Book Name<span style="margin-left:10px;">Price</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">No of Books<input style="width: 45px;" type="number" placeholder="1"></span><span style="margin-left:10px;">350</span><br><hr style="margin:0;">
              <input type="checkbox" id="you-are" name="total">Book Name<span style="margin-left:10px;">Price</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">No of Books<input style="width: 45px;" type="number" placeholder="1"></span><span style="margin-left:10px;">200</span><br><hr style="margin:0;">
              <input type="checkbox" id="you-are" name="total">Book Name<span style="margin-left:10px;">Price</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">No of Books<input style="width: 45px;" type="number" placeholder="1"></span><span style="margin-left:10px;">300</span><br><hr style="margin:0;">
              <input type="checkbox" id="you-are" name="total">Book Name<span style="margin-left:10px;">Price</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">No of Books<input style="width: 45px;" type="number" placeholder="1"></span><span style="margin-left:10px;">300</span><br><hr style="margin:0;">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="extra-col">
          <ul>
            <li><span class="autorization-redirect"><b>Total Amount</b></li><hr>
            <li style="text-align:right;"><span class="autorization-redirect">Rs.</span><span class="autorization-redirect" id="amount"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this : First of all you must use unique ids to each element in DOM, so either remove `id="you-are"` or make it unique for each checkbox. Follow the same for other elements.

You can write a click handler for checkbox and add values of price to a variable to get sum of all checked checkbox. Show value in amount span.

**NOTE** - I have removed all the ids from checkbox inputs and added closing `span` tag for amount span.

```js
$(function(){
  var totalAmount = 0;
  $('input[name="total"]').change(function(){
    //get last span which is just before the br element and read its text.
    var $priceSpan = $(this).nextUntil('br').last();
    var amount = parseInt($priceSpan.text()) * (parseInt($priceSpan.prev('span').find('input').val()) || 1);

    //if checked then add amount otherwise substract it.
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
     {
       totalAmount += amount;
     }
     else
      {
        totalAmount -= amount;
      }
    //show total amount in amount span
    $('#amount').html(totalAmount);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col1">
  <div class="field">
<div class="label-wrap">
  <label class="required" for="buy_form_pwd2">Books Required</label>
</div>
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="checkbox"  name="total">Book Name<span style="margin-left:10px;">Price</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">No of Books<input style="width: 45px;" type="number" placeholder="1"></span><span style="margin-left:10px;">250</span><br><hr style="margin:0;">
  <input type="checkbox"  name="total">Book Name<span style="margin-left:10px;">Price</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">No of Books<input style="width: 45px;" type="number" placeholder="1"></span><span style="margin-left:10px;">375</span><br><hr style="margin:0;">
  <input type="checkbox"  name="total">Book Name<span style="margin-left:10px;">Price</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">No of Books<input style="width: 45px;" type="number" placeholder="1"></span><span style="margin-left:10px;">350</span><br><hr style="margin:0;">
  <input type="checkbox"  name="total">Book Name<span style="margin-left:10px;">Price</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">No of Books<input style="width: 45px;" type="number" placeholder="1"></span><span style="margin-left:10px;">200</span><br><hr style="margin:0;">
  <input type="checkbox"  name="total">Book Name<span style="margin-left:10px;">Price</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">No of Books<input style="width: 45px;" type="number" placeholder="1"></span><span style="margin-left:10px;">300</span><br><hr style="margin:0;">
  <input type="checkbox"  name="total">Book Name<span style="margin-left:10px;">Price</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">No of Books<input style="width: 45px;" type="number" placeholder="1"></span><span style="margin-left:10px;">300</span><br><hr style="margin:0;">
</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="extra-col">
  <ul>
<li><span class="autorization-redirect"><b>Total Amount</b></li><hr>
<li style="text-align:right;"><span class="autorization-redirect">Rs.</span><span class="autorization-redirect" id="amount"></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sir it help (Y)

Comment: happy to help you :)

Comment: sir but if input number is increase the amount should also increase